# Bloquear backend Joomla IIS

Tags: html, joomla3, backend

Estoy tratando de bloquear el acceso a administrator de mi sitio Joomla para que solo permita conexiones de un cierto números de IP`s que yo ingrese en el fichero web.config . En servidores Apache hay que añadir el fichero .htaccess los siguiente:

```
order allow,deny
deny from all
allow from 8.8.8.8
```

En cambio en el fichero web.config he ayado esta documentación:

```
<location path="Default Web Site">
<system.webServer>
  <security>
     <ipSecurity>
        <add ipAddress="192.168.100.1" />
        <add ipAddress="169.254.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0" />
     </ipSecurity>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
</location>
```

En este caso bloquea esas IP´s pero lo que yo trato es de bloquear todas menos las que yo proporcione.

Ademas no se si debo situar ese fichero en la carpeta administrator que es la que quiero bloquear y sustituir **location path="Default Web Site"** por **location path="./administrator"** o dejarlo en la carpeta raiz.

Por último Joomla ya me ha proporcionado una copia con un web.config.txt se encuentra en la raiz pero al ser un .txt no tiene funcionalidad aun y todo el contenido que tiene no lo usa, si desease emplear ese fichero para hacer la restriccion de IP quitandole la extension .txt. Deberia agregar el bloque de codigo que he adjuntado mas arriba mas lo que ya habia o simplemente ingreso el bloque de código que me interesa?

Actualmente tengo esto situado en la carpeta raíz de la página y quiero bloquear únicamente la carpeta administrator que se encuentra al mismo nivel que el fichero web.config que adjunto aquí abajo:

```
<configuration>
<location path=".">
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
         <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false">
             <clear/> 
             <add ipAddress="212.142.137.10" allowed="true"/> 
         </ipSecurity>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: No estoy muy al día con Joomla pero... ¿no lo estás corriendo encima de un Apache? ¿Por qué no configurar el Apache directamente?

Comment: el servidor en el que esta montada la página es un IIS